# How expensive is to create a new Task?

Tags: c#-4.0, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am doing some asynchronous data fetching, and I need to do this in several calls to database. All these tasks need to be executed in a predefined sequence, and for this purpose I am using coroutines and Task.

```
GetItemsA(); // wrapped in new Task
GetItemsB(); // wrapped in new Task
GetItemsC(); // wrapped in new Task
```

Currently I am creating a new Task for each of these calls. Is this a bad practice, and should I try to avoid this, and  wrap all cals in a single task?

```
GetItems(); // wrap in single Task

void GetItems()
{
    GetItemsA();
    GetItemsB();
    GetItemsC();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good practice is usually to ignore overhead and focus on readability of your code. Only when you find out that some code is a bottleneck in your application, try to optimize it.

The overhead of creating a new `Task` will be most likely negligible, especially when compared with a database roundtrip.